# Measure resistance accurately with an arduino?

Tags: arduino, resistors, temperature, reference, rtd

I'm looking at performing accurate temperature measurements with a three wire RTD, and I'd like to be able to measure the resistance and thus the temperature using an arduino. The accuracy I'm looking for is better than 0.1Ω @ 100Ω.

I was told that to get good accuracy, I would first need a stable accurate low current source and very accurate low temperature coefficient resistors in a wheatstone bridge.

I was wondering if there was to better utilize the arduino's capabilities to perform this measurement, or is the external current source + wheatstone bridge the way to go?

Comment: With the many analog inputs you can easily make it somewhat autoranging. You only have a 10 bit DAC (1024 steps) so you need to figure out something smart to reach .1% resolution.

Comment: @jippie -The range is quite small, between 100 and 150 ohms.

Comment: @nubis: Have a look at LMP90080 series from TI, for an integrated solution for 3-Wire or 4-Wire RTD.

Comment: @AKR  +1.  AD7793 (and family) are in the same class as LMP90080.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Source: application note [AN687](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/AppNotes/00687c.pdf) by microchip.  It shows one of the methods of signal conditioning for 3-wire RTD.  Notice that this method doesn't require a Wheatstone bridge.

Comment: Nice :) does the final accuracy strongly depend on accurate resistor values? also, I guess one would have to get a stable voltage from the arduino